# Prevent timeout while exchange data between two stm32

Tags: uart, stm32

I am trying to exchange data (str data) between two STM32 throughout Lora connectivity. Both STM32 has a lora module and the connection between them is working fine. Based on two functions:

```
T_eError_eErrorType eDataPlane_eReceiveData_Cmd (uint32_t in_uiTimeout, uint8_t* out_pucData, uint8_t inout_pucLength, T_stSx1276_eRxPacketStatus out_pstRxPacketStatus)

T_eError_eErrorType eDataPlane_eSendData_Cmd (uint8_t* in_pucData, uint8_t in_ucLength)
```

I am trying to send and receive messages instantly. I discovered a huge problem: for example I am trying to send a data which has a duration equal to 300ms while the timeout of receiving the data is fixed to 3000 ms. It may, in one rare case, be a loss of such a data, when the data arrives at the time of 2800 ms of the timeout of the receiver. Such a problem is similar to the exchange of data in the UART interface when using the blocking mode (HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1, UART1_rxBuffer, 12, 5000);).
My question is how to garantee receiving the data without losing any byte and by using a receiving with timeout function.
Thanks in advance.